# Retrieving data from mongodb using node express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my mongodb database there are 4 collections.I can retrive data using each collection on by one.Now 
How can retrieve data from different collections in same code using key word like findone,getAll ?My model.js given below.DB ->mongodb backend  ->nodeexpress

model1.js

```
const Schema=mongoose.Schema;
const customerSchema = new Schema({

    shop:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    name:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },

    area:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
       {
    timestamps : true
    }
);
const Customer = mongoose.model('customers',customerSchema);
module.exports = Customer;
```

model2.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema=mongoose.Schema;
const distributorSchema = new Schema({


    fullName:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    warehouse:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
   phoneNo:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },

    password:{
        type : String,
        required : true
    }
},
    {
    timestamps : true
    }
);
const Distributor = mongoose.model('distributors',distributorSchema);
module.exports = Distributor;
```

Comment: Do you want to retreive all data from all collections in the db?

Comment: No. just 2 collections in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make function in your `controller.js` like this

```
export async function getDataFromTwoCollections(){

  let allData = {modelOneData : [], modelTwoData : []};
  let modelOneData = await Customer.find({}).exec();
  let modelTwoData = await Distributor.find({}).exec();
  allData.modelOneData = modelOneData 
  allData.modelTwoData  = modelOneData
  return allData
}
```

Comment: Fahad Hassan answer was very useful..Js file worked